# Audio/ Video capturing In Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: directx, windows-runtime

I am working On Audio/Video capturing from a Web Camera and this is targeted On Windows 8 Metro Style Not on Desktop Mode.
I planning to Write a Library for this So that any application can use this library to Stream Video.
Windows 8 provides Direct X and Win RT for metro mode of Windows 8. I am bit confused which one to use it for this.
Is  Win RT Alone is Sufficient for Detecting Camera and Capturing Audio/Video ?? Does Direct X Involvement is required here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out this on the Internet.So the Win RT Alone is sufficient for this.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622.

Comment: Now the Question is Which language I should use .See we can Develop Library In both C++ and C# using WinRT.
What is the Pros and Cons of using C++ and C#.See This Library will be used by UI to Display the Video.The UI can use any technology that Suits Window 8 Metro mode.So Please give your comment on this.

Comment: The sample's "Technologies" says "HTML5, Windows Runtime". Given that it specifically says it uses WinRT, why are you saying WinRT isn't sufficient?

Comment: @JoeWhite Earlier I was Confused because Media related stuff is mostly covered by DirectX in Previous Version of Windows.But In Windows 8 Direct X is at low level and all the Win RT Api inturn call Direct X api .

Answer (score 1):

There are audio/video capture APIs available in WinRT itself, under `Windows.Media.Capture` namespace. You don't need to go for DirectX. The following C# code records video with sound and saves to the 'Videos' folder of current user.

```
var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.AudioAndVideo;
var capture = new MediaCapture();
await capture.InitializeAsync(settings);

var profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);
var file = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync("captured.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
await capture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(profile, file);
```

For audio-only capture, use `StreamingCaptureMode.Audio` and `MediaEncodingProfile.CreateM4a()`

Comment: how to display it in a control?